# Using Aptana for a site that was created with FP Extensions?

Tags: css, aptana, frontpage-extensions

My site was created with FP Extensions. Will using Aptana break any extensions or cause me any functionality/appearance issues, i.e CSS, etc?

Comment: Aptana is a PHP IDE.  I was not aware that PHP could do anything with Frontpage extensions.  Be warned that Microsoft discontinued Frontpage and the Extensions a *very* long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

**Frontpage Extensions** are a server addon:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FrontPage_Server_Extensions

to make your server work with **Frontpage** client:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_FrontPage

If you use **Aptana** to modify your website you will not get any benefit from FP Extensions, but you will be able to work without issues.

Frontpage latest relase was in 2003, so you will not loose much, but Aptana is not a WYSIWYG editor.

I would suggest to uninstall FP Extensions:

http://www.gregthatcher.com/Papers/IT/frontPage.aspx

as so many exploits have been found to make it quite insecure.